# Application Crashes when using Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, crash

My application crashes after trying to login.
i created `navigationActivity` as **CHome** which i want my user to be directed to. But it keeps crashing :

> Unfortnately your app has stopped working.

But when i disabled this lines below it shows the `Toast` and no crash.

Help please

```
Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "CUSTOMER",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Intent cHome = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, CHome.class);
Common.currentUser = user;
startActivity(cHome);
finish();
```

and i have my manifest here

my CHome is as follows

```
package com.example.oracle.eliteafro;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

//import com.example.oracle.eliteafro.Common.Common;
//import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
//import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class CHome extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    //Init Firebase
    //FirebaseDatabase database;
    //    DatabaseReference salons;

  TextView loginName;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chome);


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Menu");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



        //Init Firebase
       // database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        //salons = database.getReference("el_af_salon");



        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


        //set name for user
        View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        loginName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loginName);
        loginName.setText("Beedy");
        //loginName.setText(Common.currentUser.getFullname());

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.chome, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        //int id = item.getItemId();

//        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
//            // Handle the camera action
//        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
//
//        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
//
//        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
//
//        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
//
//        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {
//
//        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your stack trace you get when your app crashes.

Comment: Can you post the code CHome?

Comment: I updated my answer, if it is not clear, please put your CHome class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare CHome as activity in your AndroidManifest.xml

**UPDATE**

I saw your updated question, so the problem is on your CHome activity, you are not getting the reference of your TextView before set the text.

```
TextView yourTextView = findViewById(R.id.your_text_view_id);
yourTextView.setText("your text");
```

**UPDATE 2**

Ok, I think that you need to pass parameters, you could pass parameters using extras.

```
Intent cHome = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, CHome.class);
cHome.putExtra("user", user);
startActivity(cHome);
finish();
```

Then on your CHome activity class you need to receive the extra :

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);
        User user = (User)  getIntent().getSerializableExtra("user");
        //now you can use your user object
       TextView yourTextView = findViewById(R.id.your_text_view_id);
       yourTextView.setText(user.getName()); // for example
    }
```

Don't forget your User class has to implements Serializable

Comment: His manifest show's he's defined the Activity in the manifest.

Comment: i commented it out and it worked.. but i need it to hold my user's name after successful registration

Comment: I updated my answer :) , check if the id of your textview reference exist on your layout

Comment: @AkinniyiBodeBolade Don't make you user object serializable. It should implement Parcelable. Serializable isn't efficient. Use Parcelable, it's the recommended pattern in Android. You'd still call the same method on your intent. The only difference is when fetching the object you call:
User user = getIntent().getParcelable("user");

Comment: Yes, if you are working with Complex objects, you should go for Parcelable :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is inside of your onCreate method for CHome, you are references a null TextView. So either, you forgot to call

```
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.your_text_view_id);
```

Or, maybe you did call that method but you passed in a id to a view that doensn't exist in your layout because findViewById will fail silently and return null instead of throughing an exception. So when you call setText() on the TextView you get a NullPointerexception.